# Unable to install any software in Ubuntu because of this error

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu, selinux

I am pretty new in Ubuntu, I am using Ubuntu 18.04 version. I was installing Odoo software but it was interrupted because of some dependency error, Now I am unable to install any software from Ubuntu Software Center because of this error, Error shown in the screen shot.

I also used following commands but still this error is occurring.

```
sudo apt update    
sudo apt upgrade    
sudo apt update    
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/listts/lock    
sudo rm /var/chache/apt/archives/lock
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/info/initramfs-tools.post*
sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/info/initramfs-tools.pre*

sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/info/bcmwl-kernel-source.post*
sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/info/bcmwl-kernel-source.pre*

sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: Please explain what your commands are doing.

Comment: i have the same problem too, and i fix it with that command.. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1990236

Comment: @DewaSembiring thank you soo much, problem resolved by trying you answer.